# select fica em branco ao dar history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Montei um sistema onde eu informo o estado e o jQuery carrega as cidades.

O problema e que quando executo um `history.back()` e volto para a página do formulário o `select` cidade fica em branco. Como faço para ele não perder o valor?

Exemplo do código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#estado").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
      $.getJSON('Cidades.php?search=', {
        estado: $(this).val(),
        ajax: 'true'
      }, function(j) {

        // Carrega as cidades
        var options = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome + '</option>';
        }

        // Adiciona cidades
        $('#cidade').html(options).show().blur();
      });
    } else {

      // Remove cidades
      $('#cidade').html('<option value=""></option>').blur();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name='estado' id='estado'>
<option value="MG">MG</option>
<option value="SP">SP</option>
</select>
<select name='cidade' id='cidade'>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que quando você utiliza a funcionalidade de voltar, o comportamento da montagem da página fica à cargo do navegador - e acredito que no seu caso, o navegador apenas recarrega o HTML que tinha em memória, sem necessariamente executar o Javascript novamente.

Uma rápida pesquisa no SO original revela [uma gambiarra que pode ser utilizada para forçar a reexecução do Javascript no Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2638357/2263584). Pelos comentários, que vão até ano passado, essa "solução" parece ainda funcionar.

```
window.onunload = function(){};
```

Acredito que deve funcionar no Opera e no Chrome. Sugiro testar em cada navegador.

Agora, se você realmente precisa levar o usuário a uma página pela qual ele já passou, e quer usar a funcionalidade de voltar para poupar tempo/processamento, eu posso sugerir que tente duas alternativas:

- abrir a página da qual você voltaria em outra aba/janela para preservar a página para a qual quer voltar, ou...;
- redirecionar para a página alvo, e se houver algo para o qual o processamento seja pesado, mantenha esse algo na sessão do usuário, em cache, ou se estiver trabalhando com ASP.NET MVC, no objeto TempData (que é feito para segurar dados que devem ter um tempo de vida curtíssimo).